# How to view sublime text 3 with view in browser plugin while WAMP is on

Tags: php, wamp, sublimetext3, sublime-text-plugin

If I write `http://localhost/Otagtransit/index.php1` while wamp is on it is OK it works. But if I use view in browser plugin and press Ctrl+ALT+ F it goes to
`file:///D:/wamp/www/Otagtransit/index.php` (here PHP codes are not run and are ommited).

In DW there is lengthy process for associating the Wamp server with DW.
How can I associate Wamp server with sublime text 3 or correct the above path (`file:///D:/wamp/www/Otagtransit/index.php`)

NOTE: A similar question has been asked but has received no answer

Comment: follow the exact path from wamp browser output

Answer (score 1):

View in Browser's [documentation](https://github.com/adampresley/sublime-view-in-browser#configure-to-view-on-local-server) clearly describes how to do this. Make sure you are using a [project](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/file_management/file_management.html#projects) to maintain your folders and files, then select **`Project -> Edit Project`** and add a `settings` section if it is not already there:

```js
{
    "folders":
    [
        {
            "path": "D:/wamp/www/Otagtransit"
        }
    ],
    "settings": {
        "sublime-view-in-browser": {
            "baseUrl": "http://localhost",
            "basePath": "D:/wamp/www"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello, @MattDMo thank you for the detailed answer. I'll check and let you know if it works. I think the trick is the "project" bit.  Best Regards...

Comment: I copied the code above and this is what I get with the Otagtransit.sublime-project file in Otagtransit folder... => https://www.google.com.tr/search?q=D:/wamp/www/Otagtransit/index.php&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gws_rd=cr&ei=yx7VVpfUIoO26ATm3ZDYDA

Comment: @Otag You gave me a link to a Google search in Turkish. Is that supposed to tell me something?

Comment: That is where the browser goes to when I press Ctrl+Alt , after changing the settings...@MattDMo

Comment: I tried this with the result that I had when I wrote down the question=> {
 "folders":
 [
        {
            "path": "D:/wamp/www/Otagtransit"
        }
    ],
 "settings":
 [ {
        "sublime-view-in-browser": {
            "baseUrl": "http://localhost",
            "basePath": "D:/wamp/www"
        }
    }
    ]
}